# TextField gets populated with previous transcription from Voice to Text engine

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm doing a chat app, I implemented a microphone and it is working good except for one thing: when I press the microphone a second time to start a new transcription, the previous one is still there and populates my TextField automatically, it is annoying. I have tried multiple things like clearing the transcription before starting the new one, clearing chatViewModel.currentInput, etc. None is working.

```
import Speech
import SwiftUI

struct ChatView: View {
    var chatId: UUID
    @State private var isTranscriptionLongEnough = false
    private let audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
    @EnvironmentObject var chatViewModel: ChatViewModel
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollViewReader { _ in
                ScrollView {
                    VStack {
                        ForEach(chatViewModel.chats.filter { $0.id == chatId }) { chat in
                            ForEach(chat.messages) { message in
                                messageView(message: message)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .padding()
                }
            }
            HStack {
                TextField("Enter a message...", text: $chatViewModel.currentInput)

                Button {
                    if !chatViewModel.currentInput.isEmpty {
                        chatViewModel.sendMessage(chatId: chatId)
                    }
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "paperplane")
                }
                Button {} label: {
                    Image(systemName: "mic.circle.fill")
                }
                .onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.1, maximumDistance: .infinity, pressing: { isPressing in
                    if isPressing {
                        startRecording()
                    } else {
                        stopRecording()
                    }
                }, perform: {})
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }

    func startRecording() {
        // Ask permission to access microphone
        SFSpeechRecognizer.requestAuthorization { authStatus in
            if authStatus == .authorized {
                // Initialize speech recognizer
                let recognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer(locale: Locale.current)
                let request = SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest()

                recognizer?.recognitionTask(with: request) { result, _ in
                    if let result = result {
                        var transcription = result.bestTranscription.formattedString
                        if !transcription.isEmpty {
                            isTranscriptionLongEnough = true
                            chatViewModel.currentInput = transcription
                        }
                    }
                }
                let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
                do {
                    try audioSession.setCategory(.record, mode: .default)
                    try audioSession.setActive(true)

                    let inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode
                    let recordingFormat = inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
                    inputNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: recordingFormat) { buffer, _ in
                        request.append(buffer)
                    }

                    audioEngine.prepare()
                    try audioEngine.start()
                } catch {
                    print("Error trying to transcribe audio: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func stopRecording() {
        audioEngine.stop()
        audioEngine.inputNode.removeTap(onBus: 0)
        if isTranscriptionLongEnough {
            chatViewModel.sendMessage(chatId: chatId)
            isTranscriptionLongEnough = false
        }
    }

    func messageView(message: Message) -> some View {
        HStack {
            if message.role == .user { Spacer() }
            Text(message.content)
                .padding()
                .background(message.role == .user ? .blue : .gray.opacity(0.7))
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))
            if message.role == .assistant || message.role == .system { Spacer() }
        }
    }
}

struct ChatView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ChatView(chatId: UUID())
            .environmentObject(ChatView.ChatViewModel())
    }
}
```

Comment: you could try using: `Button {chatViewModel.currentInput = ""} label: {  Image(systemName: "mic.circle.fill")  }`

Comment: It's not working, and my message is sent with an empty string.

Comment: very strange since you can only send a message when `chatViewModel.currentInput` is not empty in the `paperplane` button.